# creating a database in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

i am trying to create a database within my symfony3.4 but i am always facing the same error;
`       In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 115:

An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 47:

could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 43:

could not find driver`

i try to configure the php.ini but still the same problem, i used the documentation to configure my parameter.yml and config.yml

***parameter.yml***

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

***config.yml(the doctrine part)***

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'
```

and yes i know that is better to work with the latest version but i am just an employee and i am ordered to use this version: symfony 3.4 php: 7.4.9
ALSO i am using xampp on windows

Comment: Check if you have the PHP extension installed first, on the command line you can do `php -m`. Do you see `pdo_mysql`?

Comment: no i see PDO and  mysqlnd but no pod_mysql

Comment: That's probably why, you can install the PHP extension with `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql` (apt-get used in Debian distro's, so is most likely). Then make sure the extension is enabled (not commented out) in your php.ini. You will need to reload your Apache service aswell.

Comment: i am using xmapp on windows,  so how to install it ?

Comment: I am unsure to be honest, does xammp have a shell access, it should have, so you would do the command there. I assumed you would be running a Linux server if this is a work (production) thing. Edit your post to say you're using XAMPP.

Comment: Besides the fact that the extension must be installed to use a database: keep in mind that Symfony 3.4 is horribly outdated and should no longer be used for new projects. Same for PHP 7.4

Comment: same think because i am not in a prodcution stage i am just running it on my pc and it's the first step to create the database

Comment: @NicoHaase i know that but like i told you it's not my descion to take i just need a solution for a given situation.

Comment: @YassineKrout, i totally understand it is the situation you're in, but it totally baffles me how an employer in 2023 can say to specifically use v3.4 on a new project. Assuming this is a new project from your comments.

Comment: @Bossman exactly, i am not going to work on a new project, it's an old one and since it's my first month i must know this type of configuration, you know that for symfony 6 i do it and every things goes well, but it so diffrent than v3.4

Comment: @YassineKrout, i get it. What you have to do is get the `pdo_mysql` working with XAMPP. Even better, ask them for a dev machine with Linux (Debian or Ubuntu) installed. Make your job easier instead of trying to work out the middleware software.

Comment: Enabling the MySQL extension is not related to Symfony after all - it should work exactly in the same way for Symfony 3.4 and 6

Comment: @Bossman believe me i tryed but they say that it's a company policy to work on the same model and os as the other, but i will try to configure pod_mysql with XAMPP

Comment: @NicoHaase yes and that's the problem, first i  worked with v6 and i mange to make it work, but then i pass to v3.4 and it suppose to work just as fine, but it dosn't

Comment: i don't know if this can help any one, but i was modifing the xmapp php.ini file which is not the correct one, i search for the php.ini file for my php version 7.4.9 and remove the ; for the driver and it all work just fine. NicoHaase , Bossman thanks for you help .